# Vertical list in landscape and horizontal list in portrait within the same Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

**Desired Outcome**

I want to have Vertical List with custom items on the left/right side of the screen in landscape mode and Horizontal List on the top/bottom side of the screen in portrait mode. Horizontal/Vertical List should be `Fragment` so I can reuse it later for smartphone version. Minimal SDK version is 13 (Android 3.2).

**My Attempt**

My custom `Activity` has single custom `LayersFragment` and another `View`. In portrait mode fragment is aligned to parent's left. In landscape mode is aligned to parent's bottom.

`LayersFragment` has also different layout for portrait and landscape mode. In portrait mode is `Gallery` and in landscape mode is `ListView`.

Since `Gallery` and `ListView` are subclasses of `AdapterView<Adapter>` I use this parent class and `BaseAdapter` to populate items and listen `OnItemClicks`.

[image: PhotoEditorActivity Portrait mode]
[image: PhotoEditorActivity Landscape mode]

**Resource Details**

**frag_layers.xml** - XML Layout for `LayersFragment` in landscape.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**frag_layers.xml** - XML Layout for `LayersFragment` in portrait mode.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_photo_editor.xml** - XML Layout for my custom `Activity` in portrait mode. Layout for landscape mode instead of `android:layout_alignParentBottom` has `android:layout_alignParentLeft`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/photo_editor_layouts"
        class="rs.ailic.android.heritage.ui.LayersFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/photo_editor_layouts_size"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <!-- Not relevant. -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code Details**

Class **LayersFragment**.

```
public class LayersFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layers, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mLayersAdapter = new LayersAdapter();
        mLayersView = (AdapterView<Adapter>) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mLayersView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mLayersView.setAdapter(mLayersAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Not implemented
    }

    private class LayersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        //Not implemented. Returning 0 in getCount().
    }
}
```

My custom **Activity**

```
public class PhotoEditorActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_editor);
    }

    //Not relevant
}
```

**Problem**

I'm getting this ClassCastException when rotating from Landscape to Portrait (ListView -> Gallery)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState
at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onRestoreInstanceState(AbsSpinner.java:421)    
at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:8341)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchThawSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2038)
at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(AdapterView.java:766)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2024)
at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:8320)
at android.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:583)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:801)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:977)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:960)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1679)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4413)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1791)
... 12 more
```

and this one when rotating from Portrait to Landscape (Gallery -> ListView)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState
at android.widget.AbsListView.onRestoreInstanceState(AbsListView.java:1650)
at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:8341)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchThawSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2038)
at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(AdapterView.java:766)
```

How can I solve this problem or should I look for another solution?

**My Opinion**

The problem appears when screen orientation change. I believe that the problem is in 'default implementation' of `ListView` and `Gallery`. They try to restore their `SavedState` in `onRestoreInstanceState` after orientation change, but the `View` has changed and ClassCastException is thrown.

Thank you,

Aleksandar Ilić

Comment: Excellent use of the images to describe what you want and I'm _very glad_ to see the logcat reports, but they are out of context without the relevant code.

Comment: In general without knowing exactly how you are instantiating your fragments the simple (but possibly not the best) answer is to make sure both views (listview and gallery) are present in both of your layouts and just set the visibility to gone for the view you don't want shown.  


To give a better answer I think you need to tell us how you are constructing your fragments (code via fragment manager or XML) setting up in your onCreateView in your fragment

Comment: @Idistic I have updated the question with relevant code. The idea is to avoid having both views and use their common super class `AdapterView<Adapter>` to do the job. It's possible because `AdapterView` has all necessary methods.

Comment: Overriding the restore save/restore state might work, to be honest I have never had a need to do that but it seems reasonable. My approach would be more lazy (LOL) I would make sure the layouts had both views, gone for landscape/portrait respectively and then just attach the adapter to the correct one dependent on orientation, of course if all you had to do was modify the save/restore and it was trivial to do that would be more elegant.

Comment: @Idistic Overriding `onRestoreInstanceState` is not as simple as it sounds. You have to call super method to avoid some 'NotCallingSuperMethod' `exception` and also one of super methods is checking if given `Parceable` is an instance of perticular private inner class and always throws `ClassCastException`. I've practicly rewritten that inner class but it's still throwing `CCE`. Maybe reflection could help or some hack to change class signature. Your approach is backup plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**

Solution written below is 'light solution' and only avoids `ClassCastException`, it's not final yet. Fine tuning is certainly necessary. Since Java Reflection is used and field names are hardcoded it's possible to fail on platforms where names are changed or differently implemented.

I'll update this answer with more details as soon as I finish writting my application.

**Solution**

You have to override `onRestoreInstanceState` in `ListView` and `Gallery`. In both of them you have to do proper conversion. In `ListView` you convert given `Parceable` to `AbsListView$SavedState` and in `Gallery` to `AbsSpinner$SavedSate`.

**VerticalList** - Modified `ListView`

```
public class VerticalList extends ListView {

    public VerticalList(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(SavedStateConversion.getAbsListViewSavedState(state));
    }
}
```

**HorizontalList** - Modified `Gallery`

```
public class HorizontalList extends Gallery {

    public HorizontalList(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HorizontalList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HorizontalList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(SavedStateConversion.getAbsSpinnerSavedState(state));
    }
}
```

**SavedStateConversion** - AbsListView$SavedState <-> AbsSpinner$SavedState. Conversion is done using **Java Reflection**.

```
public class SavedStateConversion {

    private SavedStateConversion() {}


    /**
     * Converts <code>android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState</code> to <code>android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState</code>.
     * @param state parcelable representing <code>android.widget.AbsSpinnerSavedState</code> 
     * @return parcelable representing <code>android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState</code>
     */
    public static Parcelable getAbsListViewSavedState(Parcelable state) {
        try {
            Class<?> gss = Class.forName("android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState");

            /*
             * List of all fields in AbsSpinner$SavedState:
             * 
             * int position;
             * long selectedId;
             */

            Field selectedIdField = gss.getDeclaredField("selectedId");
            selectedIdField.setAccessible(true);
            Field positionField = gss.getDeclaredField("position");
            positionField.setAccessible(true);

            Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
            parcel.writeLong(selectedIdField.getLong(state));
            parcel.writeLong(0);
            parcel.writeInt(0);
            parcel.writeInt(positionField.getInt(state));

            Class<?> lvss = Class.forName("android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState");
            Constructor<?> constructors[] = lvss.getDeclaredConstructors();
            Constructor<?> lvssConstructor = constructors[0];
            lvssConstructor.setAccessible(true);

            return (Parcelable) lvssConstructor.newInstance(parcel);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        throw new RuntimeException("Conversion from AbsSpinner$SavedState to AbsListView$SavedState failed!");
    }

    /**
     * Converts <code>android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState</code> to <code>android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState</code>.
     * @param state parcelable representing <code>android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState</code> 
     * @return parcelable representing <code>android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState</code>
     */
    public static Parcelable getAbsSpinnerSavedState(Parcelable state) {
        try {

            Class<?> lvss = Class.forName("android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState");

            /*
             * List of all fields in AbsListView$SavedState:
             * 
             * String filter;
             * long firstId;
             * int height;
             * int position;
             * long selectedId;
             * int viewTop;
             */

            Field selectedIdField = lvss.getDeclaredField("selectedId");
            selectedIdField.setAccessible(true);
            Field positionField = lvss.getDeclaredField("position");
            positionField.setAccessible(true);

            Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
            parcel.writeLong(selectedIdField.getLong(state));
            parcel.writeInt(positionField.getInt(state));

            Class<?> gss = Class.forName("android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState");
            Constructor<?> constructors[] = gss.getDeclaredConstructors();
            Constructor<?> gssConstructor = constructors[0];
            gssConstructor.setAccessible(true);

            return (Parcelable) gssConstructor.newInstance(parcel); 
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Conversion from AbsListView$SavedState to AbsSpinner$SavedState failed!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the fragment is not placed on the backstack and the fragment instance is not retained (mainly because I don't know the effect either will have), onCreateView will be run every time the orientation changes. Hence, you can designate which layout to use based on the current orientation. It is also critical to have different IDs for the ListView and Gallery.

Use getFirstVisiblePosition and setSelection to remember the current adapter position. This will only reliably work if the data positions in the adapter don't change when the fragment is not in the resume state . If the data does change, you'll have to recalculate the appropriate position to set to the AdapterView.

**frag_layers.xml** - XML Layout for LayersFragment in landscape.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**frag_layers.xml** - XML Layout for LayersFragment in portrait mode.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@android:id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Class **LayersFragment**.

```
public class LayersFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    private AdapterView<Adapter> mLayersView;
    private LayersAdapter mLayersAdapter;
    private int mVisiblePosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        if (mLayersView != null) {
            editor.putInt("visiblePosition", mLayersView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        } else {
            editor.putInt("visiblePosition", 0);
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mVisiblePosition = prefs.getInt("visiblePosition", 0);
        // -- Set the position that was stored in onPause.
        mLayersView.setSelection(mVisiblePosition);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView;

        rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layers, container, false);

        switch (getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            mLayersView = (AdapterView<Adapter>)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
            break;
        default:
            mLayersView = (AdapterView<Adapter>)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            break;
        }        

        mLayersAdapter = new LayersAdapter();
        mLayersView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mLayersView.setAdapter(mLayersAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // -- Populate mLayersAdapter here or through a data ready listener registered with the activity?
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Not implemented
    }

    private class LayersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        //Not implemented. Returning 0 in getCount().
    }
```

I haven't tested this code but it's a similar implementation that I use. For my implementation, remove the code in onResume and onPause except for the super calls. During onPause, instead of storing the first visible position in the preferences, I store it directly with my data which the fragment can then use later when it loads the data into the adapter. This also makes it relatively simple to calculate the new position if data is added before or after the current position. Any data updates are then relatively straightforward. The fragment learns of the update through a listener, modifies the Adapter based on the changes, and sets the the correct adjusted position of the AdapterView.

Depending on how many changes are made to the adapter at one time, you might also want to use Adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false) when creating a new adapter and use Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after updates to the adapter. This prevents notifying the AdapterView the data has changed until after all changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to bind alternating views to one BaseAdapter, why not use two appropriate Adapters and simply pass the relevant information between the different views.

Something like this:

```
mListView.setPosition(mGallery.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

and vica versa. You'll probably need to save this information in onPause() since I don't know if you can reference the first *visible* position of a View that is no longer visible.

Comment: The problem is not in BaseAdapter because adapter is not implemented. I think I need to override onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() in ListView and Gallery and convert previous SavedState for the new UI component.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very interesting approach.  Pre-fragments, I'd say you had your work cut out for you, because the code sort of naturally expects variant XML layout files to have the same types of controls with the same IDs.  But, as you know, with a Fragment, all you have to do is say where it goes and link it to a class.  I see no reason why you couldn't have different layouts (e.g., portrait and landscape) instantiate different Fragment classes.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid two different Fragments (portrait and landscape) because the code is basically the same. The IDs of UI controls are the same, but the type is different. I hopping to find solution for smooth  transition between Gallery and ListView.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using two listviews that are different (one with expandable),make sure they have different id in the xml layout.